# Estoy tratando de hacer un trigger que inserte a un usuario y al mismo tiempo haga un update de ese insert cambiando el valor de una columna

Tags: sql, sql-server

Este es mi codigo, el problema es que me pone como null todos los registros que no sean el mismo

Eso es lo que estoy tratando de insertar, entonces por ejemplo en mi tabla persona el nuevo registro tiene el id 16, entonces en mi tabla Usuario hay una columna con la fk de persona que esta entrando como null, entonces el trigger deber poner el 16 en lugar del null, y lo hace, pero me deja como null los datos de las columnas anteriores

```
Create TRIGGER trigger_rel_ahorasix8
ON Usuario
after INSERT
AS 
    DECLARE @idPersona int =
                (select top 1  id_persona from Persona ORDER BY id_persona DESC)
    DECLARE @idUsuario int = 
                (select id_usuario from INSERTED)
        update Usuario set Usuario.id_persona = (@idPersona)
        where id_usuario = @idUsuario
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hay varios problemas con tu trigger. Sería mejor si pudieras poner datos de prueba, el insert que quieres hacer y los resultados esperados después del insert y el trigger.

Comment: INSERT INTO Persona values ('Carlos Medina','Quijada','Medina',22,9457832,9993605416,1,'Calle 179', 'Foto', 1,1,1,1,'1997-06-03')

INSERT INTO Usuario values ('carlosx13@gmail.com','Joshua123',null,2,1)

Comment: Eso es lo que estoy tratando de insertar, entonces por ejemplo en mi tabla persona el nuevo registro tiene el id 16, entonces en mi tabla Usuario hay una columna con la fk de persona que esta entrando como null, entonces el trigger deber poner el 16 en lugar del null, y lo hace, pero me deja como null los datos de las columnas anteriores

Comment: Edita la pregunta y usa los nombres de las columnas porque nosotros no conocemos la estructura de tus tablas.

Comment: Si bueno, pero ese es mi problema

Comment: Ya esta, ya lo actualice

Comment: Lectura obligatoria https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 + Un título contiene la idea esencial y nada más.

Comment: Broder soy nuevo, ahora solo necesito que funcione eso y después me leo documentación de como hacer una pregunta.

Comment: que significa esto "pero me deja como null los datos de las columnas anteriores"? cuales columnas anteriores? de que registros, del registro recien insertado? de los que ya existian? Si esperas que nos tomemos el tiempo de ayudarte, tomate un poco de tiempo también en redactar una pregunta buena, leer la documentación de como preguntar te va ayudar más a vos, que a los que respondemos.

Comment: esta en la imagen la columna que me deja null.

Comment: título != descripción. Arregla por favor. Gracias :D Por cierto `Broder soy nuevo, ahora solo necesito que funcione eso y después me leo documentación de como hacer una pregunta` >>> saber cómo preguntar genera mayor chance para que obtener respuesta más certera. Te lo digo en buen plan.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que en lugar de usar un trigger para eso, uses la variable @@IDENTITY.

Es decir, en el stored procedure donde haces el insert puede hacer esto:

```
    declare @IdPersona int

INSERT INTO Persona values ('Carlos Medina','Quijada','Medina',22,9457832,9993605416,1,'Calle 179', 'Foto', 1,1,1,1,'1997-06-03') 

set @IdPersona = @@IDENTITY

INSERT INTO Usuario values ('carlosx13@gmail.com','Joshua123',@IdPersona,2,1)
```

No especificas la estructura de la tabal Usuario, así que asumo que ahí donde puse la variable @IdPersona es donde va esa campo, creo que la idea está clara.